# Grails file upload to file system

Tags: grails, upload

I can't find a good explanation of how to upload files to the file system in Grails. The tutorial books I've gone through "keep it simple" by uploading directly to the database using a `byte[]` field, but that wouldn't be ideal for my particular situation. The Grails documentation explains file uploading here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles. So I tried modifying this to fit my resource:

```
def save(Person personInstance) {
    // ... a couple standard error checks

    // Handle file upload
    def f = request.getFile(params.thumbnail)
    if (f.empty) {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        return
    }

    def filename = "myfile.txt"
    def webrootDir = servletContext.getRealPath("/") //app directory

    f.transferTo(new File(webrootDir,"images/uploads/thumbnails/$filename"))
    personInstance.save flush:true

    // ... response
}


Could not find matching constructor for:
java.lang.String(org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile)
```

I also tried using the name of the field, `def f = request.getFile('thumbnail')`, but got the same error. I made sure to add the `g:uploadForm` tag and set the `<input name="thumbnail" type="file"/>` within the form.

I would like to be able to upload an image to the file system and then use a `String` field in the database to store the name of that image.

Comment: See "File upload" section @ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-grails06099/